# Including excel file in the jar to be created

Tags: maven-2, build

I have some excel templates for report generation.
I need to include these templates into the jar that is being created by the maven-jar-plugin
how can i do so?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Just adding the files to the resources directory should work.

Answer (score 0):

As Jorn has commented above, place the excel templates that you need to be packaged into the resources folder of you rmaven project, which is by default `src/main/resources`. maven jar plugin will automatically take them and place them in the jar.